Should I use standard PAG 46 oil to lube seals when installing DENSO compressor pre-filled with ND-8?
update
Turns out I mis-ordered and it's not a Denso with ND-OIL 8, it's a GDP with PAG 46. So the question for me is moot. But assuming it gets answered, the answer may help somebody else. Or even me in a few months/years if this GDP compressor fails. So I'll leave it here.
/update
I'm planning to install a new AC Compressor, condenser, seal kit, and expansion valve in a 2006 Honda Ridgeline.
The (OEM) Denso compressor was shipped pre-filled with ND-8.
Was going to pick up a small container of oil to lube the new seals with.  But now know that ND-8 while a PAG 46 oil, isn't the quite the same as the standard PAG 46 at the local auto parts store.
So I'm wondering if it's ok to use standard PAG 46 to lube the seals.  Or if I should pour a little of the ND-8 out of the compressor and use that; pouring any leftover back in.
Or do I bite the bullet and order ND-8 (or apparently ND-12 see below) and wait for it to get here before tackling this?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm no AC expert, so will let someone else answer for sure, but I've always been told to use the same PAG (or AC lubricant) oil to lube the seals/o-rings as what is called for inside the AC unit.

Yeah, that was my thinking...just wondering if I can use a little out of the compressor or if that might cause a problem.

Check again. R134a systems use oil that readily absorbs moisture. If used as seal lube, oil will absorb moisture from air and corrode fittings. R12 or mineral oil is recommended. Drug store baby oil, mineral oil is a good substitute. Mineral oil does not absorb moisture. Just a little lube on each seal to let it slide into place.

@FDryer check what again?  And baby oil or mineral oil?  Everything I've seen says to only use AC oil.

GM specifically states not using pag oil for ac o-ring lube. R12/mineral oil only. Mineral oil does not absorb moisture. Aluminum corrodes. Your choice to do it right or accept long term consequences of incorrect repairs, the leak no one wants. Some links to read; https://www.manuf-rubber.com/news/what-is-the-best-lubricant-for-o-rings/, https://www.blingstrom.com/diy-project/2019/7/15/diy-ac-o-ring-replacement-keeping-your-cool-when-the-temps-rise-professional-equipmentoperators-necessary, https://www.oreillyauto.com/detail/c/murray-climate-control/chemicals---fluids/grease---lube/graphite-lubricant/1efe28ee2d3e/murray-climate-control-4-ounce-silicone-o-ring-lubricant/mry0/59019, https://www.napaonline.com/en/p/NCB56204 Here's a forum devoted to vehicle ac systems, addressing seal lube; https://autoacforum.com/viewtopic.php?p=26860&hilit=o+ring+lube#p26860
Use service manuals for guidance.

The Honda SM says "Replace the O-rings with new ones at each fitting, and apply a thin coat of refrigerant oil before installing them. Be sure to use the correct O-rings
for HFC-134a (R-134a) to avoid leakage."
Of course that assumes the OEM Denso with double end capped ND-OIL 8.
